# Why I can not viusualize plotly python code in jupyter lab?

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter-lab, plotly-python

I installed the plotly package for my anaconda (on Jupyter lab).

I run the following code to see the visualization and nothing appeared.

Please how do I solve this?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23]),
    go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=animals, y=[12, 18, 29])
])
# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Do you get any error message? Or it appears to run fine but produces no output?

Comment: What are version of JupyterLab and plotly you use?

Comment: Try to restart the kernel and clear output and plot it again. Because it worked on my jupyter normally.